# Error while loading project: Attribute Include is unrecognized

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, merge

After merging two branches the Visual Studio has suddenly problems with loading a project.
When I try to reload, I always get the error

> The attribute "Include" in element Reference is unrecognized.

I have no idea why this happened... how can I get the solution to load the project again?
Has anyone encountered this error message before and know what I have to look for to find the problem?

The .csproj doesn't really look corrupt on the first sight...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the error... there was a merge conflict with a Reference-Tag with no close-tag because it was deleted while merging.

Comment: Your answer perfectly fixed my compilation error at a critical situation. Thanks for your valuable data.

Answer (score 7):

when you build the csproj file with MSBuild you get the line-number on which the error occurs. This is unfortunately not visible in VisualStudio.

- Open the Develop Commnand Prompt for Visual Studio
- Navigate to the folder which contains the csproj file
- Run MSBuild

In the error, it contains the line-number with the error in the csproj file.
This helped me fixing the file after a GIT merge

Comment: Visual Studio should do this.

Comment: EXCELLENT workaround.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer from xeraphim actually pointed me to the right direction, but for me I had an additional `</Reference>` tag in my csProj file, hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, I couldn't solve it until I remove VS 2019 then install it again which fixed it nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

My case was that I had nested Reference tags, and this error was triggered by kdiff3 plugin using Git Extensions.